# Url parsing with regex

Tags: python, regex, url

I have several urls. I want to parse a certain number, so that I can save it to a variable like:

```
if number ==15 : 
    category ='tree'
elif number ==20:
    category ='flower'
elif number ==3:
    category ='bird'
```

The urls are of the form:

```
http://www.test.tw/in/15   
http://www.test.tw/in/15?page=2  
http://www.test.tw/in/15/#/?page=3
http://www.test.tw/in/20/#/?page=2
http://www.test.tw/in/3/?page=5
```

So far, the method I'm using:

```
urls = (
    ('http://www.test.tw/in/15','tree'),    #category =x[1]
    ('http://www.test.tw/in/20','flower'),   
    ('http://www.test.tw/in/3','bird'),   
)
```

But when the url has something like this `?page=2` it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want the regex for that?

Comment: I think yes.Just can let me save to the variable: category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to search your pattern, and then use a dictionary instead of the `if-else` chain:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'/in/(\d+)')
categories = {'15': 'tree', '20': 'flower', '3': 'bird'}

def getcategory(url):
    category = pattern.search(url).group(1)
    return categories[category]
```

### Example

```
urls = ['http://www.test.tw/in/15',
        'http://www.test.tw/in/15?page=2',
        'http://www.test.tw/in/15/#/?page=3',
        'http://www.test.tw/in/20/#/?page=2',
        'http://www.test.tw/in/3/?page=5']

print [(url, getcategory(url)) for url in urls]
```

*Output*:

```
[('http://www.test.tw/in/15', 'tree'),
 ('http://www.test.tw/in/15?page=2', 'tree'),
 ('http://www.test.tw/in/15/#/?page=3', 'tree'),
 ('http://www.test.tw/in/20/#/?page=2', 'flower'),
 ('http://www.test.tw/in/3/?page=5', 'bird')]
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use regular expression.

Use [`urlparse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) ([`urllib.parse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) in Python 3.x):

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.urlparse('http://www.test.tw/in/15/#/?page=3')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.test.tw', path='/in/15/', params='', query='', fragment='/?page=3')
>>> urlparse.urlparse('http://www.test.tw/in/15/#/?page=3').path.rstrip('/').rsplit('/')[-1]
'15'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `urlparse` as suggested by others and look into regex as last resort.

```
(?<=\/)\d+(?=\/|\?|$)
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/rZ7lQ2/6)

sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?<=\/)\d+(?=\/|\?|$)', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"URLs"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression as well, but urlparse is needed still.
Combining the two you could do this:

```
import urlparse
import re
my_url = urlparse.urlparse('http://www.test.tw/in/15/#/?page=3')
my_match = re.match(r"/in/(?P<num>\d+)/$", my_url.path)
my_match.group("num")
>> 15
```

However you can really see that this is brittle and reliant on that all of the urls look the "same", but it works for Django :)

Answer (score 0):

for a regex-based approach:

```
import re
list = ["http://www.test.tw/in/15", "http://www.test.tw/in/15?page=2",
        "http://www.test.tw/in/15/#/?page=3",
        "http://www.test.tw/in/20/#/?page=2", "http://www.test.tw/in/3/?page=5"]
urls = ()
categories = {"tree": [], "flower": [], "bird": []}
for i in list:
    category = int(re.search("(http\:\/\/.+)\/(\d+)", i).group(2))

    if category == 15:
        urls += ((i, "tree"),)
    elif category == 20:
        urls += ((i, "flower"),)
    elif category == 3:
        urls += ((i, "bird"),)

print urls
```

**output**

```
(('http://www.test.tw/in/15', 'tree'), ('http://www.test.tw/in/15?page=2', 'tree'), ('http://www.test.tw/in/15/#/?page=3', 'tree'), ('http://www.test.tw/in/20/#/?page=2', 'flower'), ('http://www.test.tw/in/3/?page=5', 'bird'))
```